# "Unable to load one or more of the requested types" when creating new Xamarin application

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I get this error when I create a new blank Android app in Visual Studio 2015.Full error is this:

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. 
Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

Any possible fix? I reinstalled both Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it by clearing my AppData/Local folder and repairing Visual Studio, then running VS as admin for the first time

Comment: What do you mean by "Clean my AppData/local folder" ?